# Where can I find Texinfo documentation?

Tags: documentation, tex, manpage, info, texinfo

I want to write the manual for an open-source software. As the manual will contain several pages I considered *texinfo* the best option since the manual will be too long for a man page and the user should be able to open it in a ssh session.

However, I can not find a good tutorial or manual and the official documentation is too cryptic. Can you share a tutorial or manual about texinfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

texinfo is a TeX format to typeset files in the GNU info format, so you are looking for a tutorial of that format. GNU info is documented in its own format, so a starter is the command

```
info info
```

on a GNU/Linux computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can not really see *texinfo* documentation using `info info`

Comment: @Vicente Adolfo Bolea Sánchez As I said before, the input format for texinfo is just the GNU info format; there is no special texinfo input format.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know and use Emacs, you might want to write the document in Org-mode.  Org can export to PDF, `man`, HTML, TexInfo, and other formats. Documentation and other info is available at http://orgmode.org/.

If you do not know Emacs, it has a rather steep learning curve. It might not be worth the investment in time (unless you plan on doing more of this sort of work in the future).